# Can't explain why `_.debounce` works in this way?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I use lodash debounce to prevent users press keyboard twice in a very short of time. Below is the code which doesn't work:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', _.debounce((e) => this.keyDown(e), 300), false);
```

But it works if I change to:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', this.debounceKeyFunc.bind(this), false);
debounceKeyFunc = _.debounce((e) => this.keyDown(e), 300);
```

`debounceKeyFunc` is a method of the instance of the current class as `this.debounceKeyFunc`.

I don't understand why I need to define a separate function to debounce the key event callback in order to make it work.

Comment: Its the other way round? The second snippet wont work. -> [mcve] please

Comment: Both versions are correct and will work.

Comment: @dfsq im not shure that one can access a variables value before it is set...

Comment: @JonasW. OP just posted it this way, `debounceKeyFunc` is a method of the instance of some object available as `this.debounceKeyFunc`.

Comment: @dfsq It looks identical but the first one doesn't work

Comment: @ZhaoYi it does work....https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/8869/. Please provide an example.

Comment: I think it doesn't work in a class context. I don't think jsfiddle support babel to transpile the `class` definition.

Comment: @ZhaoYi of course it works in class context too, depends on how you set up. But since you didn't provide complete code it's hard to say the problem.

Comment: @dfsq looks like Markus gives a good explaination. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- edit -- Actually, what I wrote is true but doesn't apply here.
debounce is only called once when the handle is registered and should work.
The first also does work for me, except for the face that this is not defined

-- edit --

You have to ensure the debounced function is only created once, because it holds an internal state that is used for the debouncing, remembering when it was last called.

In your first example, the debounced function is created on every event, meaning debouncing starts anew every time, meaning there is nothing to debounce because every event get's it's own debouncing.

I hope that explains it, otherwise just ask.

Comment: That makes sense for my problem. But could you explain why `https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/8869/` doesn't have such issue. I would say the debounce starts every time on a new event, right?

Comment: @ZhaoYi See my updated answer. So what case causes you trouble?